# how to redirect request to many backend server using nginx

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

It's like this

```
http {
    upstream VoiceObjects {
        server 172.22.23.92:8099;
        server 172.22.23.92:8100;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/host.access.log main;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://VoiceObjects;
        }
    } 
}
```

But I don't want to use proxy_pass, I want to redirect request to backend server without create a proxy request.
I tried "rewrite" syntax but seem like rewrite doesn't work with upstream.
So, any idea ?

Comment: if you redirect then your port number will appear in the URL, is that what you want ?

Comment: With or without port number is ok. Just want to redirect request to more other domain use round robin like upstream.